# CSS - Mobile menu placement issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a mobile menu into a responsive sectioned site.

The mobile menu is placed within a relatively positioned header block.  When actived the mobile menu is absolutely positioned - which pushes its parent content upwards - possibly due to the height of teh content - the content remains in place when closed (IOS Firefox).  I'm struggling to figure a solution where the menu can be positioned as required and show at the correct width without screwing everything up when the menu opens!?  Other than fixing the position of the menu - which would mean the content scrolls beneath - which isn't ideal - does anyone have any ideas?

Site build here (mobile width to re-create problem) - http://www.liquidclients.co.uk/landsail/ls2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this on line 140 in landsail_mobMenu.css:

```
#nav {
position: fixed;
top: 75px;
left: auto;
}
```

Comment: this would fix the entire menu in place though - including the menu icon - so the page would scroll beneath it - cheers for trying though